# How to get Stylus working with Webpack 3?

Tags: webpack, stylus, webpack-style-loader

I'm really struggling to get the Stylus CSS preprocessor working with a current version of Webpack. Here's what I've attempted:

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'mwe.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: /src/
            },
            {
              test: /\.styl$/,
              include: /src/,
              use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                  }
                },
                'stylus-loader'
              ],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Inside of `/src` I have a very simple `app.js` and `style.styl`.

When I run Webpack, `/dist/mwe.js` gets generated as expected, but I also would have expected a CSS file to be generated from the Stylus file. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Webpack doesn't emit `.css` files if you're using `style-loader`. You need to use [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to get the CSS file(s).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Panya, you will need to install `ExtractTextPlugin` first.

1. `npm i --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin`
2. Then include it in
   you webpack.config.js

```js
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '../css/style.css',
  allChunks: true,
});

const config = {
  …
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|styl)$/,
        use: extractPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader', 
              options: {importLoaders: 1, sourceMap: true}
            },
            {
              loader: 'stylus-loader',
              options: { sourceMap: true },
            },
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [extractPlugin]
  …
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to extract/convert the .styl file directly to a css file. I am trying to import it into an .scss file. eg. `@import 'sprite.styl';` How do I do this? I am using Webpack 4....

Comment: You're gonna need to add a `sass-loader` and you don't need the plugin, thus it's quite a different task. Do you want to make a new question and link it in a comment?